# Shared Access 2010 database is in an inconsistent state

Tags: database, database-connection

I have a shared accde file on a network drive.  Occasionally we will have an inconsistent state problem.  The error message appears below.  It seems to be associated with network connection interruptions for even one user.  We have an example when a user unplugged the Ethernet and switched automatically to wireless and other examples where users have left the database open overnight, perhaps when a machine hibernates.

Once this happens the one user cannot work and no one can open the accde file.  Other users who have the database open can continue to work.

After the problem occurs it remains until everyone closes the database.  At that time it completes whatever recovery it requires and all users can get back in.

This was disruptive when we had six users in one room.  Now we have 17 in two cities and a few work-from-home users.  It's becoming intolerable.

The obvious answer is to move away from Access.  We're working on it but it's a long way off.  In the mean time I would appreciate any advice.

Is there a way to prevent the problem entirely?
Is there a VBA way to detect the problem in the instances that are not showing the error message?
Is there something I'm not thinking of?
What would you do?

Error message:
Microsoft Access has detected that this database is in an inconsistent state, and will attempt to recover the database.  During this process, a backup copy of the database will be made and all recovered objects will be placed in a new database.  Access with then open the new database.  The names of objects that were not successfully recovered will be logged in the "Recovery Error" table.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that Microsoft gives is Splitting the database, which just means to put the data elements on a shared server, and everyone has their own copy of the front end.
This might cause problems if that front end needs to be updated (e.g. additional  forms). Details here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/microsoft-office-has-detected-that-this-database/3fb41c70-f7ba-41dd-a847-e62203071466?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

Check the row count in the tables, the tables most likely have large amounts of data creating latency on the read and write queries, causing the locking.

Archive older data and keep the database small and neat, perhaps create referenced databases for archived information

Answer (score 0):

I gather that your MS Access database is getting corrupt when up put it on a shared drive. A Microsoft Access database may get corrupt when in a multi- user environment. Here are the workaround that you can use in order to fix it.

Step 1: Run Command Prompt as Administrator
Click on the Windows icon and type Command Prompt. Then right-click on the Command Prompt and choose Run as administrator option.

Step 2: Execute Compact and Repair Database Command
In the command prompt window, type the following command and then press ‘Enter’.
msaccess <database file name> /compact
In the command, replace <database filename> with database path. For instance,
msaccess "C:\Program Files\Reports.mdb" /compact
This will start the process to compact and repair the faulty Access database file.

Otherwise, You can check out this thread for an alternative solution :  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/ms-access-mdb-ldb-database-corrupted/171275#171275